# How to create an application with CPack?

Tags: cmake, cpack

First of all I would like to ask how I can create an application with cpack in general?

Specifically I have a program with a cmake configuration where I install the following dependencies.

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ARCHIVE  DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY  DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME  DESTINATION bin
)
install(DIRECTORY resources DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Now I want to create a DMG file, .deb file or windows installer
for my application.

How can I do that?

When I run `cpack -G "OSXX11"` I get a DMG file. However when I install it and try to start the application, the application doesn't open.

Also when I run `make install` it installs an command and not an application.
This means when I execute `programname` the application starts correctly,
however when I try to start the application via the spotlight search, an empty window starts. probably this happens because the application is written with gtkmm3 and glade it cannot find the resource file.

Comment: `This means when I execute programname the application starts correctly` - That is, if you switch to install directory and run executable, than it works. `however when I try to start the application via the spotlight search, an empty window starts.` - And if you do not switch to install directory, then application doesn't work. Do I correctly understand what do you mean? If so, it is your **application** which cannot run outside of install directory. Packaging is unrelated.

Comment: programname -> any directory in the terminal

spotlight -> program starter in the Application directory

Comment: These are steps for the second case, when application is failed to run, right?

Comment: Yes, in the second case the application is failing.

Comment: So, as I said before, your application is just failed to run if one don't switch into install directory. It is not a problem with CMake script, installation or CPack, it is **a problem with your application**.

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. What does this has to do with the install directory. When I execute the program via the command line (not in the install directory) it runs perfectly fine. however when I start the application I get from cpack it does not run. => My program is just an executable which I can run. I just want to wrap it into an installer.

Comment: `When I execute the program via the command line (not in the install directory) it runs perfectly fine.` - Do you run **installed program** (that is located in the *install* directory), or just *built one* (located in the *build* directory)? You question post is so unclear... And comments help a bit.

Comment: Of course I run the executable in the install directory and not the one in the build directory. I am not even in the build directory

Comment: Ok, but to recap I would be comfortable with just an answer on how to configure cpack that I get an installer, as stated in my first sentence.
The rest of this post was just to give you some insights where I am struggling.

Comment: `I would be comfortable with just an answer on how to configure cpack that I get an installer` - Unless you want something *special*, it is sufficient to **just run** `cpack`, as you already has done. That is why your question has a little sence without a clear problem description. Well, lets take a view from the other side: `make install` just create several files under install directory. Could you check, that installing DMG file, obtained from `cpack`, **also creates these files**, with the same names and content? This could give a key to your problem.

Comment: Your question is quite broad and you can easily learn about how to do this by reading the official documentation: [mastering cmake book](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Packaging%20With%20CPack.html), [CPack module reference docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html) will help you for starters. Then you can look at specific docs for specific package generators as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things you need are handled in this project:

https://github.com/kracejic/cleanCppProject